# apache rewriterule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am quite new to apache rewrite rule.
Now I want to redirect the url

```
http://maywedding.0577sz.com/
```

to

```
http://maywedding.0577sz.com/special
```

My rule now is:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule / /special [NC]
```

But this does not works as I expected.
How to write the rule in the .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^(www\.)?danrenjian\.com$
RewriteRule ^/$             http://www.example.com/special [R,L]
```

Comment: An empty path is not a valid HTTP [request URI](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-5.1.2).

Comment: @phihag Thanks for letting me know. I thought it started after the `/`, not including the `/`. I edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

[NC] has no effect, since your rule only consists of a slash. Instead, you probably want

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/$ /special/ [R]
```

to send an HTTP redirect instead of internally rewriting the URL. Don't forget to restart the apache server with `apache2ctl restart` or `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`.

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/$ /special/ [R] just add a back slash after 'special', and it works, thank you.

Comment: @hon Well, the question said you wanted to redirect to `/special`, without a trailing slash. Fixed in this answer anyway. If this or PaulPRO's answer solves your problem, consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it. If neither does, but you've solved the problem, write your own answer and accept it.